# SSDT schema compare - ignore system service brokers (VS 2013)

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, schema-compare

I have a database project in my solution and a database imported from windows azure via SSMS "Import data-tier app..." option. When using schema compare, the comparison shows system "service brokers" (message types, queues, etc.) in the delete section. When I apply the update, everything works, but these system service brokers are not deleted and appear again and again.

[image: Unwated items to be deleted]

I suppose that it is not possible to delete them, but **is there a possiblity to ignore them in the schema compare**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the settings icon (looks like a cog on the compare tool toolbar) and then navigate to the `Object Types` tab you should be able to select/deselect the object types you wish to include/ignore in your comparison.

The icons in the `Object Types` tab match those in the comparison so it should be pretty easy to ignore what you wish to ignore.

Comment: It is almost what I was looking for! Is there a way to change the default setting? Now, everytime I create a schema compare it resets to the full view. Or is it "better" to save the schema comapre to the solution?

Comment: I've always just saved the schema compare to the solution. It also helps to keep tract of any objects you've "unselected" in the comparison.

Comment: I saved two of them, one for dev and one for test database and it seems to work just fine, thanks.